# Basic model of Perceptron functions not giving the required result after running iterations Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, target, perceptron, nested-for-loop

The iterations after executing the codeblocks is supposed to give a progressive increase in the weights value and finally the last arrived weights should be displayed. But the output is giving the same weights for all the iterations. I am new for the coding. Where am I going wrong?

The final output required is [[0],[0],[0],[0]] and weights expected as answer is [[-0.0405],[-0.0288],[-0.0066]]

The Function code blocks as below.

```
from numpy import *
    import numpy as np

class pcn:
    def __init__(self,inputs,targets):
        if np.ndim(inputs)>1:
            self.nIn=np.shape(inputs)[1]
        else:
            self.nIn=1
        
        if np.ndim(targets)>1:
            self.nOut=np.shape(targets)[1]
        else:
            self.nOut=1
            
        self.nData=np.shape(inputs)[0]
        
        self.weights=np.random.rand(self.nIn+1,self.nOut)*0.1-0.05
        
        
        
    
    def pcntrain(self,inputs,targets,eta,nIterations):
        
        inputs=np.concatenate((inputs,-np.ones((self.nData,1))),axis=1)
        
        change = range(self.nData)
        
        for n in range(nIterations):
            
            self.activations=self.pcnfwd(inputs);
            self.weights=eta*np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),self.activations-targets)
            
            print('Iteration: {}'.format(n))
            print (self.weights)
            
            #activations=self.pcnfwd(inputs)
            
            print('Final outputs are : {}'.format(activations))
                  
            
           # return self.weights
        
        
    
    def pcnfwd(self,inputs):
        activations=np.dot(inputs,self.weights)
    
        return np.where(activations>0,1,0)
```

The input code statements are

```
inputs=inputs = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
targets=np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])   # XOR Targets
```

The main code blocks are

```
p=pcn(inputs,targets)
p.pcntrain(inputs,targets,0.25,15)
```

Code output as of now which need to be corrected as progressively changes in weights till final iteration.

```
Iteration: 0
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.  ]
 [-0.25]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 1
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 2
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 3
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 4
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 5
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 6
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 7
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 8
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 9
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 10
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 11
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 12
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 13
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
Iteration: 14
[[ 0.25]
 [ 0.25]
 [-0.5 ]]
Final outputs are : [[1 1]
 [1 1]]
```

Comment: In your `for-loop`, nothing is being updated...  after the first pass through, don't you want to update the inputs or something?  You are missing a math step in here to update necessary things for the 2 -> N iterations.

Comment: @AirSquid The loop is required to print the results of each iterations. If any corrections required in the statements please advise

Comment: You are computing on `inputs` each time.  Don't you want to update `inputs` with the result of each iteration?  You are calling the same function with the same (non-updated) inputs, so it will be same result--as you are seeing.  Don't you want to update the input with some result...  `inputs = inputs + delta` ... during the loop

Comment: @AirSquid Please advise how to get that. can you comment on that part of code to make the changes accordingly. I presume this part makes that. /n

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand what math you are trying to do.  In the loop, you are calculating `activations` and `weights`.  What is supposed to happen after that?  (in plain English...)  :)

Comment: @AirSquid Please advise how to get that. can you comment on that part of code to make the changes accordingly. I presume this part does that function of recalculating with the learning rate.Appreciate your support.       self.weights=eta*np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),self.activations-targets)

Comment: @AirSquid Thank you for helping me to the issue. There was a sign missing('=' instead of '- =' ) in the iteration statement due to which the iteration was not happening. The weights are not arrived as expected as may be due to random initialisation of weights ,i presume but not sure. But the loop is now working fine and getting the results for OR output of array.That issue is resolved now. In the book i was referring there is no seed set to tally the answers.      Where as in XOR the output is not coming as expected with 15 iterations. The algorithm does not converge.Not sure why???